# Cubase doesn't export stereo

Tags: drums, electronic-music, vst, cubase

In my arrangement, I set panner left/right for different instrument channels. It sounds good but when I export the file, the final export wav file doesn't reflect the left/right features, it sounds like a mono audio.

1. I tried many **sample rate** and **bit rate** combinations, no luck.
2. I tried to export with **L/R Channels selected**, no luck.

What am I missing? Why doesn't my work and export doesn't sound alike?

Comment: Any chance of a screenshot of your channel strips?

Comment: @tolga - I'll put this on hold for now. You'll need to do as Bob asks: give us more info. Screenshot of settings will help